# French names for adoptive/foster parents

Tags: traduction, noms-de-famille

Are there special terms in French for adoptive/foster parents?

In the style of *papa/maman, papy/mamie, pépé/mémé*?

**Background:** As I was picking my child from *la crèche* yesterday, a lady came, and the child said: "C'est la maman de X !" The lady answered: "Je ne suis pas la maman de X - je suis sa mamoute(??), nous sommes la famille d'acceil. Mais c'est presque la même chose." (The French rendition is mine, so it might be faulty.)

Thus, I am wondering whether there are more or less widespread terms for the members of *la famille d'acceuil*.

Comment: Are you looking for terms used by children to call their "parents" or more like some kind of translation of these terms?

Comment: @LaurentS. I have expanded my answer, to explain why I pose this question.

Comment: OK then jlliagre is right in his answer that there is no specific name. From what I've heard of foster parents, each has their own way of dealing with it. It seems in this case this foster mother chose/proposed something reminding of "maman" without being exactly it. That's more intimate that just a firstname, and more close to the truth than "maman"

Comment: Il peut être utile de faire la distinction entre parents d'adoption et famille d'accueil. Le premiers sont juridiquement les parents et sont généralement appelés papa/maman. La seconde est plus une solution d'hébergement provisoire et de cadre éducatif. Elle ne détient pas l'autorité parentale qui reste l'apanage des vrais parents. C'est pourquoi l'usage de papa/maman dans le cas d'une famille d'accueil n'est pas vraiment approprié.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No specific nickname I'm aware of.

I suspect in most cases, adoptive/foster parents are called *maman/papa* if they agree/encourage it or are just called by their first names.

Invented nicknames like the one you heard are of course also possible, e.g.:
*mamoute / papoute*
*mamoune / papoune*
*mamounette / papounet*
*mamouche / papouche*
*mamanou / papanou*
...